# API validation laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, api, validation

I need make an api with laravel 5.7, the api is not a problem itself.

I need make a strict validation for the current model and nested relations objects for save, example.

Imagine a model Posts with a relation comments.
I have stored my data in database as:

```
    [
      {id: 1, user_id: 1, title: 'my title post', comments: [{id: 5, comment: 'my comment for post id 1'}]},
      {id: 2, user_id: 1, title: 'my second title post', comments: [{id: 15, comment: 'my comment for post id 2'}]},
      {id: 8, user_id: 2, title: 'my third title post', comments: [{id: 25, comment: 'my comment for post id 8'}]}
    ]
```

My user_id logged in the api is `1`
If I try send a `POST http` to update a post and a comment how I can validate the user logged in the `api` is the owner of each object? example of post:

POST to update.

```
    [
      {id: 1, user_id: 1, title: 'my title post modified', comments: [{id: 5, comment: 'my comment for post id 1'}]},
      {id: 1, user_id: 1, title: 'my title post modified 2', comments: [{id: 25, comment: 'my comment for post id 1'}]},
      {`id: 8`, user_id: 2, title: 'my title post', comments: [{`id: 25`, comment: 'my comment for post id 1'}]},
    ]
```

how example show, I can modify only the first and second object of my array but I can't modify the comment in the second object.

hope I have expressed myself correctly.

Comment: don't you have a column in Posts table to save the write? like author_id?

Comment: @FatemehMajd its `user_id` in the post table

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you get your Post data in `JSON` format, with double quotes `"` surrounding keys and Strings. And Create JSON data in Laravel - PHP like :

```
$postsData = '[
  {"id": 1, "user_id": 1, "title": "my title post", "comments": [{"id": 5, "comment": "my comment for post id 1"}]},
  {"id": 2, "user_id": 1, "title": "my second title post", "comments": [{"id": 15, "comment": "my comment for post id 2"}]},
  {"id": 8, "user_id": 2, "title": "my third title post", "comments": [{"id": 25, "comment": "my comment for post id 8"}]}
]';

$posts = json_decode($postsData);

//var_dump($posts);

$authUserId = 1;

foreach($posts as $post) {
  if($authUserId == $post->user_id) {
      echo 'User own this Post...<br/>';
      echo $post->id.' - '.$post->title;
      foreach($post->comments as $comment) {
              echo '<br/>';
              echo '----'.$comment->id.' - '.$comment->comment;
              echo '<br/>';
      }
      echo '<br/>';
  }
}
```

Output will be that only Post 1 and 2 can be saved for User 1 :

```
User own this Post...
1 - my title post
----5 - my comment for post id 1

User own this Post...
2 - my second title post
----15 - my comment for post id 2
```

Comment: its not a bad idea, but I was think it can be performed with some middleware or request for each model? or someting else using the framework utility, laravel is a powerful framework I think someone before was make a similar this.

Comment: If you think it then there's probably some laravel package for that. After I checked that, I found one [laravel-nestedupdater - Github](https://github.com/czim/laravel-nestedupdater) with 8 stars, so not very popular, but claim to do the job. There's probably others, but I don't think Laravel has one built-in yet. It would be awesome if they made it. But the more you can keep your codes away from 3rd-Party packages, the better it will be for you when you need to upgrade your codes.